# Does the Rieger-Nishimura lattice over a subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$ stabilize?

Tags: lo.logic, gn.general-topology

**Notation:** If $U,V$ are open subsets of a topological space $X$, let us write $U\Rrightarrow V$ for the Heyting operation: the largest open subset $W$ of $X$ such that $U\cap W \subseteq V$ (i.e., the set of points $x\in X$ in a neighborhood of which $U$ is included in $V$; or $\newcommand\interior{\mathop{\mathrm{int}}}\interior(V \cup (X\setminus U))$ if you will), and $\newcommand\mytilde{\mathop{\sim}}\mytilde U$ for $U\Rrightarrow \varnothing$ (the largest open set disjoint with $U$, that is, $\interior(X\setminus U)$), the pseudocomplement of $U$.

Given an open set $P$ of a topological space $X$, let us now define the **[Rieger-Nishimura lattice](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Rieger-Nishimura.svg)** over $P$, a sequence $(P_m)$ of open sets of $X$, by induction on $m$, as follows:

- $P_{-1} = \varnothing$
- $P_1 = P$
- $P_{2n+2} = (P_{2n+1} \Rrightarrow P_{2n-1})$ for $n\geq 0$, which also happens to be $P_{2n} \Rrightarrow P_{2n-3}$ when $n\geq 1$
- $P_{2n+3} = (P_{2n+1} \cup P_{2n+2})$ for $n\geq 0$, which also happens to be $P_{2n+1} \cup P_{2n+2}$ when $n\geq 1$

so this starts as follows

- $P_2 = \mytilde P$
- $P_3 = (P \cup \mytilde P)$ is the complement of the boundary $\partial P$ of $P$
- $P_4 = \mytilde\mytilde P$ is the smallest regular open set $\newcommand{\regularopen}{\mathop{\mathrm{ro}}} \regularopen P = \newcommand{\closure}{\mathop{\mathrm{cl}}} \interior\closure P$ containing $P$ (viꝫ. the set of points in whose neighborhood $P$ is dense)
- $P_5 = (\mytilde P \cup \mytilde\mytilde P)$ is the complement of $\partial\regularopen P$
- $P_6 = (\mytilde\mytilde P \Rrightarrow P)$ is the set of points in whose neighborhood $P$ is regular open

…after which I start to lose intuitive sense of what the $P_m$ mean.  But the set of all $P_m$ together with $P_\infty := X$ is the Heyting algebra generated by $P$, i.e., the smallest set of open subsets of $X$ containing $P$ and stable under $\cap$, $\cup$ and $\Rrightarrow$.

We have $P_m \subseteq P_{m'}$ when $m\leq m'$ except possibly when $m=2n+1$ and $m'=2n+2$ or when $m=2n$ and $m'=2n+2$ for some $n \geq 0$.  In particular, if $P_m = X$ then all $P_{m'}$ are also $X$ eventually (for $m' \geq m+3$).  For example, starting from $P := \mathopen]-1,0\mathclose[ \cup \mathopen]0,1\mathclose[ \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we have $P_7 = \mathbb{R}$ and $P_m = \mathbb{R}$ for $m\geq 9$.

Now in general it is possible for the $P_m$ for $m<\infty$ to be all distinct from $X$, but this will be for some specially fabricated topological space $X$.  What I don't know, and this is my question, is whether this can occur for $X = \mathbb{R}^k$:

**Question:** Is there $P \subseteq X$ open with $X := \mathbb{R}^k$ such that the $P_m$ are all distinct from $X$?  Or to ask an even more specific question, if we call $m_0(P)$ the smallest $m \in \mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ such that $P_m = X$ for $m$ (which we might call the “Rieger-Nishimura rank” of $P$), what are the possible values of $m_0(P)$ for $P \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$?  (The answer could depend on $k$ for all I know.)

(My first intuition was to try to connect this “Rieger-Nishimura rank” to the Cantor-Bendixson rank of the complement of $P$, but I don't think they're related at all.)

Comment: This seems somewhat related to Kurstowski's complement-closure theorem, but that doesn't quite apply here because of the unions

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Indeed, and my first reaction when thinking about this was “how might it possibly give more than 7 different open sets when complement and closure only give 14?”, but, as you point out, the unions makes the problem different.

Answer (score 3):

The notation in the question prevents me from discussing a sequence of sets or applying the Rieger–Nishimura operations in several spaces at once, hence I will write $R(P,X,m)$ for what you denote $P_m$.

There is such a $P\subseteq\def\R{\mathbb R}\R^k$ for each $k\ge1$. First, intuitionistic propositional logic is complete with respect to the topological semantics when the topological space is fixed as $\R^k$ (this is true for every dense-in-itself separable metrizable space, see A. Tarski, [*Der Aussagenkalkül und die Topologie*](https://eudml.org/doc/213024), Fundamenta Mathematicae 31 (1938), no. 1, pp. 103–134). This by itself implies that for each $m$, there exists $P$ such that $R(P,\R^k,m)\ne\R^k$. Better yet, we can fix sets $P_m\subseteq(m,m+1)^k$ such that $R(P_m,(m,m+1)^k,m)\ne(m,m+1)^k$. It is easy to check that $R(P,X,m)\cap U=R(P\cap U,U,m)$ for any open $U\subseteq X$, thus taking $P=\bigcup_mP_m$, we have $R(P,\R^k,m)\ne\R^k$ for all $m$.

Comment: This answers my question, and I didn't know that the frame of opens of $\mathbb{R}^k$ is complete for intuitionistic propositional calculus. But I admit I was hoping for an explicit example of an open set $P$ with all $R(P,X,m)$ distinct, because the point is to help my intuition with $R(\bullet,\bullet,m)$ for $m$ large. Do you think Tarski's paper is “constructive” (in an informal sense of the word) so that it could provide such an example?

Comment: (I fixed the reference, which mistakenly pointed to a review of Tarski’s paper rather than the paper itself.) The argument is more or less constructive, but intuitively I’d say it’s not very helpful (you construct a tree of sets inductively by manipulating basis elements to get what you want them to do).